# How to quickly create a dummy menu?

Tags: menus

I want to create a dummy menu with 1 or 2 level of depth. I know I can create the menu via the administration module, but I want to know if there is something I can use to generate fast a dummy menu.

I have a file with the sitemap indented by spaces that look as follow:

```
Home
Foo
    Foo 1
    Foo 2
    Foo 3
Bar
Baz
    Baz 1
    Baz 2
        Baz 2.1
        Baz 2.3
```

Is there something to rapidly create the menu hierarchy into WordPress 3.6?

Answer (score 3):

Why not make it just once, then use that database for all your development sites?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test This has a link to a test database you can import (XML I believe), which has a few menus if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Build your menu once, then export and import using the standard WP plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/ . Also accessible from WP Admin -> Tools -> Import/ Export.

Answer (score 0):

Install a theme with menu support (Twenty Thirteen).

Then go Appearance -> Menus -> Menu name -> type a string -> Create menu -> Pages -> Select a page -> Add to menu -> Save menu

Boom!

Comment: Yes but I have a menu with about 52 items... I want to do it quickly without repeating that 52 times...

Comment: Added an alternative answer.